# passing arrays to function in javascript

Tags: javascript

hey guys I actually asked this question some days ago. I am still here trying to make it work. but am getting `undefined` how so ?

```
function map(f, a) {
  var result = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i != a.length; i++) {
    result[i] = f(a[i]);
  }
  document.write('<br>the result of the computation is: ' +
    result[i]);
}

var myArrays = [2, 3, 4, 5];
var myFunction = function(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
map(myFunction, myArrays);
```

I actually thought I had done enough to get this to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: What do you think should be output, and what is actually being output?  Have you stepped through this in an IDE debugger (such as any modern browser js console)?

Comment: the output was supposed to be a multiplication of the array elements passed to the function earlier defined in the map function. that is to be displayed via: document.write('<br> the result of ypur computation is: ' + result[]); and it gives me this : the result of your computation is : undefined.

Comment: try, document.write('<br>the result of the computation is: ' +
    result[i-1]);

Comment: i really cant see what i didnt defined

Comment: actually in result array you have 4 elements as last index is 3 and your i value after loop is 4 so result[4] is undefined

Answer (score 0):

> for (`INITIALIZATION`; `CONDITION`; **`AFTERTHOUGHT`**) {}

By the time you are logging it, value of `i` is incremented hence you are accessing an item from array which *does not exist*, there is no item at mentioned index so value is `undefined`.

Pass `result` instead of `result[i]` or better to use `console.log` for debugging and pass argument as `result`. Rest of the code is working fine.

```js
function map(f, a) {
  var result = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i != a.length; i++) {
    result[i] = f(a[i]);
  }
  console.log('<br>the result of the computation is: ' +
    result);
}

var myArrays = [2, 3, 4, 5];
var myFunction = function(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
map(myFunction, myArrays);
```

Comment: thanks Ray. but can you share more light on why the undefined?

Comment: Take it this way, If there is an array having value as `[1]`, it means you have an item at index `0`, in your case you are trying to access the value at index `1`, as there is no value at index `1`, it will be evaluated as `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

its `undefined` as you increment `i` past the array length in the `for` loop `i++`, then try to retrieve `result[i]` in `document.write`. remove the `[i]`:-

```js
function map(f, a) {
  var result = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i != a.length; i++) {
    result[i] = f(a[i]);
  }
  document.write('<br>the result of the computation is: ' + result);
}

var myArrays = [2, 3, 4, 5];
var myFunction = function(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
map(myFunction, myArrays);
```

> thanks that really worked fine , but can you really share more light
>   about what happened that led to the undefined ?

`i` starts at 0, then every time the `for` loop is looped. `i` gets incremented (`i++`). when the `for` loop is finished, `i` is now 1 higher than the greatest index in `myArrays`. therefore when you try to get `result[i]` in the `document.write`, there is no value at that index, resulting in `undefined`

Comment: thanks that really worked fine , but can you really share more light about what happened that led to the undefined ?

Comment: BenG thanks was really helpful. please can you recommend any site that will help improve my javascript skills?

Comment: if you issue is now resolved. please mark the answer which was most helpful as correct by clicking the tick.